# Update ListView: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, listview

i would to know how to update a listview each time it is opened or recovery. I put this code but does not work as it should. Any suggestions?

```
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
adapter = db.getAdapter();
variable.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh/update lsitview

Comment: setAdapter do it already @Raghunandan

Comment: @blackbelt on yes he is doing it in `onResume`.

Comment: Are you sure the adpater contains element to display?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```